# jquery compare this with an extra value

Tags: javascript, jquery, find, compare

How can I compare `$(this)` with the value of `data-id` that could be `1-2rju-aodg`.

I mean that I need to specify that `$(this)` has the tag `data-id` and I need to verify it is equal to `X`

```
$(this).data('id')/*==123123akfsna*/.siblings('p').html(no_featured_news).removeClass('existing').addClass('description');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to use `if`:

```
$(this).filter('[data-id="1-2rju-aodg"]').siblings('p')........
```

Comment: This is slightly slower (theoretically) than thecodeparadox's answer because of the extra method call.  I'm not sure how, but apparently `this + 'string'` in a jQuery selector does expand to a proper selector.  It's weird because `console.log(this)` seems to print nothing.

Comment: @ExplosionPills. **1.** I would use my version because it's simpler and clearer. **2.** I'm not sure it slower. Anyway, `filter` is the function for those kind of things.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(this + '[data-id=123123akfsna]')
      .siblings('p')
      .html(no_featured_news)
      .removeClass('existing')
      .addClass('description');
```

**[Working Sample](http://jsfiddle.net/thecodeparadox/nxvuE/2/)**

Comment: @Vega. That's weird!, anyway Look at my answer, this is how it should be done.

Comment: @gdoron I know.. but still I am trying to understand how `$(this + '[data-id=123123akfsna]')` works

Answer (score 1):

```
if ($(this).attr('data-id') == '1-2rju-aodg') {
   $(this).siblings('p')//...
}
```

Comment: I don't want it in a if condition, I'm trying @thecodeparadox 's version. Tnks anyway (:

Comment: @w0rldart that one will work too; why not have it in a conditional?

Comment: @w0rldart. use `filter` then.

Comment: +1, I think this should be the answer, but for his request I added another way without `if`.